# Does MySQL Workbench need server to operate?

Tags: mysql, connection

I have to solve problem with the database connection.

I checked the ip address and port but my pc's host doesnt allow the connection.

Do I have to own a server to use MySQL workbench?

Comment: Check the firewall on your computer, and the server hosting the MySQL instance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

MySQL Workbench connects to a MySQL Server instance. However, you can install MySQL Server on your own machine. Server and client(s) can co-exist on the same machine.

You can download the latest open source MySQL Server (currently version 5.1.50) from:

- [MySQL :: Download MySQL Community Server](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/)

Comment: +1 exactly right. One quick addition, I believe @King is confused about needing a "server" - when we talk about a "MySQL Server", it isn't a physical box with chips in, it's another bit of software that you install on your normal computer (for development purposes).

Comment: @Sohnee: Yep good point. The MySQL server is the DBMS software. A MySQL client is another piece of software to interact with the DBMS using SQL. MySQL Workbench is one such client.

Comment: @Daniel-Vasallo, I'm new to MySql, I want to try it all on my Ubuntu. I see a client, a server and a workbench.  Need I to install all three?  Thank you very much!